# Arduino uno and a rotary encoder

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a solution for an arduino uno R3 and rotary encoder that will count each time you rotate the encoder clockwise and decrement when rotated counterclockwise. All other solutions to this problem were very convoluted and unsatisfactory so i solved it myself. Below you can see the code listing, you should be able to copy and paste into a new sketch file and upload without any problems. 
Thanks, 
Cameron Belt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //rotary encoder

int pin1 = 2;//a
int pin2 = 3;//b
int reset = 11;

int previousA;
int previousB;

int counter = 20;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(pin1,INPUT);
  pinMode(pin2,INPUT);
  pinMode(reset,INPUT);

  digitalWrite(pin1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pin2,HIGH);

  attachInterrupt(0,encoderRead,CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(1,encoderRead,CHANGE);

}

void loop()
{
  if(digitalRead(reset) == LOW)
    counter = 20;
}

void encoderRead()
{

  int a = digitalRead(pin1);
  int b = digitalRead(pin2);
  //Serial.print(digitalRead(pin1));
  //Serial.print(digitalRead(pin2));
  //Serial.println();
  if(previousA == HIGH && previousB == HIGH)
  {
    if(a == LOW && b == HIGH)
      {
        counter += 1;
        Serial.println(counter);
      }
     else if(a == HIGH && b == LOW)
     {
       counter  -= 1;
       Serial.println(counter);
     }
  }

  previousA = digitalRead(pin1);
  previousB = digitalRead(pin2);
}
```

Connect the rotary encoders outside pins (when looking at the side with three pins) to inputs 2 and 3 on the arduino and if you have a push button on your encoder connect one pin of the switch to pin 11 on the arduino with a pull up resistor (10k should be sufficient) from that pin to Vdd and the other pin of the encoder switch to ground. Connect the middle pin of the encoder on the side with three pins to ground. 
Once uploaded to the arduino open the serial monitor and turn the rotary encoder.